# Notepad ++ Regex replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to convert

```
http://website.com/cat/movie/nameofmovie.html
```

to this

```
http://website.com/cat/movie
```

So I have tried `[/].*(html)` But this applied from first `/` char, Is there any way to specify 5th `/` in the line?
Is there any method to inverse replace?

Comment: Do you specifically want to remove the everything after the 5th `/` or the last part of the link?

Comment: I want to remove all after the 5th /

Answer (score 4):

If you want to specifically remove everything after the 5th `/` and removing this 5th slash, you can use:

```
((?:[^/]*/[^/]*){4})/.*html
```

And replace with `$1`.

---

If you want to remove the last part of the link with the last slash, you can use:

```
/[^/]+html
```

And here since you don't have any capturing group, leave the replace with box blank.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace directly `/\w+\.html` with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `/[^/]+(\s+|$)` with nothing. If you have to filter with hmtl files, just add the extension like this: `/[^/]+\.html(\s+|$)`.